# Sorting using an index number

Tags: vb.net

How do i implement a index based sort in vb.net

Could someone guide me. By giving me a head start

eg

array  = 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Index Number = 5

Counting from 9 and the 5th character is 5.

So the first sorted character is 5.

Remove 5 and remains 9 8 7 6 4 3 2 1

start value should be from 4(current 5th character) now 5th character is 9 since it's circular

unsorted array : 8 7 6 4 3 2 1

sorted array : 5 9

any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I definitely wouldn't call this "sorting"; it's a bit more like deterministically (non-randomly) "shuffling" the array. But I'll take a stab at this…

Basically, start by using [`List(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) rather than arrays, because they allow you to easily and remove at any point in the list, rather than arrays which are a fixed size. Next, use a running counter to track your current position in the input list, and use the [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) operator to make the index effectively 'wrap' around the end of the list. Use a [`While`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) loop to continue until all the items from the input have been processed. It should look something like this:

```
Dim input As New List(Of Integer) From { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
Dim stepBy As Integer = 5
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim output As New List(Of Integer)
While input.Count > 0
    index = (index + stepBy - 1) Mod input.Count
    output.Add(input(index))
    input.RemoveAt(index)
End While
```

In this case the output is:

```
5, 9, 3, 6, 7, 4, 1, 8, 2
```

Comment: wow...this worked perfectly...+1 for the answer although i just needed a hint. thank you...will yr answer as a reference and try it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was an interesting question and I loved the answer by p.s.w.g....

...but I was curious to see if any of the built-in .Net collections would facilitate a fairly trivial circular list.

This is what I came up with using the [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim originalIntegers() As Integer = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

        Dim output As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim circleInts As New CircularIntegerList(originalIntegers)
        circleInts.MoveForward(4) ' move forward 4 from the 1st to get the 5th slot
        While circleInts.Count > 0
            If circleInts.Current.HasValue Then
                output.Add(circleInts.Current)
            End If
            circleInts.RemoveCurrent() ' next number in sequence becomes the current one
            circleInts.MoveForward(4) ' move forward another 4, net jump is 5 from the deleted one
        End While

        Dim result As String = String.Join(",", output.Select(Function(x) x.ToString).ToArray)
        Debug.Print(result)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CircularIntegerList

    Private values As New LinkedList(Of Integer)
    Private _current As LinkedListNode(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New(ByVal data() As Integer)
        If data.Length > 0 Then
            values = New LinkedList(Of Integer)(data)
            _current = values.First
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Current As Integer?
        Get
            If Not IsNothing(_current) Then
                Return _current.Value
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
        Get
            Return values.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub RemoveCurrent()
        If Not IsNothing(_current) Then
            Dim tmp As LinkedListNode(Of Integer) = If(IsNothing(_current.Next), values.First, _current.Next)
            values.Remove(_current)
            If values.Count > 0 Then
                _current = tmp
            Else
                _current = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub MoveForward(Optional ByVal NumberOfJumps As Integer = 1)
        If Not IsNothing(_current) Then
            For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfJumps
                _current = If(IsNothing(_current.Next), values.First, _current.Next)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```